# react native Invalid hook call

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I use Redux and Redux Saga for my Auth. I want to test it, and If I click on my button (auth button) then it should redirect to Home. But I get this error:

Invalid hook call

Why?

```
import { all, take, call, put, fork } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import { authProccess, authFailure, authSuccess } from '../slice/auth';
import authApi from '../../../api/auth';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

function* register(payload) {
  try {
    const navigation = useNavigation();
    const res = yield authApi(payload).then(res => res).catch(e => e);
    yield navigation.navigate('Home');
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}

function* watcher() {
  while(true) {
    const { payload } = yield take(authProccess.type);
    yield fork(register, payload);
  }
}

export default function* () {
  yield all([watcher()]);
}
```

This code works fine until I add use Navigation and navigation.navigate

Answer (score 0):

hooks can only be used inside functional components,

How I would do it, I would update in reducer to auth: true, then navigate from the screen if auth is true.